# Problem occured when install numpy for python3.4 on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, python, numpy

When I tried

```
pip3 install numpy
```

I got the error as

```
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
```

Then I continue to install python-dev but got failed too.

I've also tried

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

and got

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-numpy : Depends: liblapack3 but it is not going to be installed or
                      liblapack.so.3
```

Comment: Make sure `python-dev` is installed

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing what it says. Installing dependencies?

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev liblapack3
```

Comment: I updated my OS and then everything is solved although I still don't know why. Thanks anyway.